# Best way to replace a property in an array of objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
const organisations = {
  fetchingData : false ,
  error : null,
  data : {
    totalCount : 68,
    data : [
     { indID : 12345, name : 'abc'},
     { indID: 12, name : 'xyz'}]
  }
}

const checkedBy = {
  data : {
    name : 'PQ',
  },
  indID : 12345,
}
```

I would like to replace the name property inside the `organisations` object by the name property of `checkedBy` object when indID matches with the array of the data array of the `organisations` object

Comment: Please share what have you tried ?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the mapper function you want?

```js
let org = {
  fetchingData : false ,
  error : null,
  data : {
    totalCount : 68,
    data : [
     { indID : 12345, name : 'abc'},
     { indID: 12, name : 'xyz'}]
  }
}

const checkedBy = {
  data : {
    name : 'PQ',
  },
  indID : 12345,
}

console.log("Before :: \n", org)

org.data.data = org.data.data.map(x => {
 if(x.indID === checkedBy.indID){
    x.name = checkedBy.data.name
  }
return x;
})


console.log("After :: \n", org);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can easily achieve the result using [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

```js
const organisations = {
  fetchingData: false,
  error: null,
  data: {
    totalCount: 68,
    data: [
      { indID: 12345, name: "abc" },
      { indID: 12, name: "xyz" },
    ],
  },
};

const checkedBy = {
  data: {
    name: "PQ",
  },
  indID: 12345,
};

const obj = organisations.data.data.find((o) => o.indID === checkedBy.indID);
obj.name = checkedBy.data.name;
console.log(organisations);
```

```css
/* This is not a part of answer. It is just to give the output fill height. So IGNORE IT */
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

you can mutate the `organisations.data.data` in the following way.

```js
const organisations = {
  fetchingData: false,
  error: null,
  data: {
    totalCount: 68,
    data: [{
        indID: 12345,
        name: 'abc'
      },
      {
        indID: 12,
        name: 'xyz'
      }
    ]
  }
}

const checkedBy = {
  data: {
    name: 'PQ',
  },
  indID: 12345,
}

//replace name
organisations.data.data = organisations.data.data.map(org => {

  if (org.indID === checkedBy.indID) {
    return {
      ...org,
      // replace name with checked by name
      name: checkedBy.data.name
    }
  }

  return org

})

console.log(organisations.data.data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Find the node from the `organizations` object and update the node, if its found.

```js
const organisations = {
  fetchingData: false,
  error: null,
  data: {
    totalCount: 68,
    data: [
      { indID: 12345, name: 'abc' },
      { indID: 12, name: 'xyz' }]
  }
}
const checkedBy = { data: { name: 'PQ' }, indID: 12345 }
const updateNode = organisations.data.data.find(node => node.indID === checkedBy.indID);
updateNode ? updateNode.name = checkedBy.data.name : {};
console.log(organisations);
```